# DataFrame filter column

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following dataframe 'X_df'

which city has the 5th highest total number of Walmart stores (super stores and regular stores combined)?

```py
data_url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/1962_2006_walmart_store_openings.csv'
x_df = pd.read_csv(data_url, header=0)

x_df['STRSTATE'].where(x_df['type_store'] == 7)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Dataframe.max()` to get the max city count the get the city name

```
X_df=df[X_df['city_count']==X_df['city_count'].max()]

x_df["city_name"]
```

Comment: Hi! Can you please see my edit. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

I think something like this is what you want? :

```
data_url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/1962_2006_walmart_store_openings.csv'
x_df = pd.read_csv(data_url, header=0)

city_store_count = x_df.groupby(['STRCITY']).size().sort_values(ascending = False).to_frame()
city_store_count.columns = ['Stores_in_City']
city_store_count.iloc[4]
```

The fifth biggest is actually a shared 3rd place with ten stores, so you could print the top 10 for instance:

```
city_store_count.head(10)
```

Comment: Hi, can you please see my edit!

Comment: I've added a new solution, it counts all stores in each city and sorts the counts. You get the 5th biggest at index 4, or you can print the whole list :)

Comment: Side note:  As you can see, the fifth is actually a shared 3rd place with 10 stores in each city.

Comment: Thanks you good sir

Comment: Hope it works! You can accept my solution if it was helpful :)